# Detect and replace emojis in a string with php

Tags: php

I use this preg replace to remove all emojis in a string:

```
$data['message'] = preg_replace("/([0-9|#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}|\x{00a9}|\x{203C}|\x{2047}|\x{2048}|\x{2049}|\x{3030}|\x{303D}|\x{2139}|\x{2122}|\x{3297}|\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?/u", "", $data['message']);
```

This works very well but I dont want to remove them. Instead I have to replace them with a bbcode. That means every emojis in a string should replaced with a own bbcode.

**Example:**

```
U+1F600
```

becomes

```
[emoji]1f600[/emoji]
```

or

```
U+1F603
```

becomes

```
[emoji]1f603[/emoji]
```

Is this possible? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

I had a try with the pattern you are using and it seems that it doesn't match all the existing unicode emojis.

In fact, I find it quite complicated to understand completely how emojis are built, especially because they are made of one code point and then they can be modified with the use of sequences. Typically, you can have a variation of an emoji to change the skin color of a face. Another example of the family icon of two women and two girls  `‍‍‍‍` you build it with this sequence: `‍ + U+200D + ‍ + U+200D + ‍ + U+200D +`

I found the interesting explanations here: https://www.contentful.com/blog/2016/12/06/unicode-javascript-and-the-emoji-family/

But to come back to your question, your `preg_replace()` seems to be a
quick, almost working solution. I first wrote another pattern which
seems to include more cases:

```php
$data['message'] = preg_replace(
    '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}\x{2700}-\x{27BF}\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}\x{24C2}-\x{1F251}\x{1F30D}-\x{1F567}\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u',
    '[emoji]$0[/emoji]',
    $data['message']
);
```

Don't ask me how I found the list of ranges. I just googled around and then had a try with regex101 until it worked with a huge bunch of emojis. I saved it here: https://regex101.com/r/bLuezV/2

**But, I noticed that my test on regex101 just above isn't working
for the sequences** (typically the family example above). It looks
like it is working because of the highlight, but no, it's not
handling the sequences. **So we have to find a better regex pattern!**
This is way too much work to handle all the correct cases and the
pattern will be difficult to maintain.

#### Using a PHP lib will be far safer

I think it's better to use a specific lib to do what you are looking for. It will certainly be updated when new emojis come out.

The text file containing all the latest sequences:
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-test-regex-pattern/blob/main/dist/latest/index.txt

**This PHP project could help you**: https://github.com/aaronpk/emoji-detector-php

Also, consider using any other PHP *Composer* package (as projects
often change and are replaced by newer ones). Typically, just by
searching for `emoji` on packagist.org: https://packagist.org/?query=emoji

#### JavaScript introduces the `v` flag

In *JavaScript*, since 2023,
[the **v**nicode flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag)
gives us the possibility to match simple emoji icons, but also
**emojis made of multiple code points, with the help of**
`\p{RGI_Emoji}`.

This makes things quite easier: https://regex101.com/r/bLuezV/6

Comment: At first, WOW, thank you very much for your detailed answer. I appricate it very much.  I have test it and the $0 seems to be empty. Because the result is [emoji][/emoji] Maybe you could have a look again? And yes, its really quite complicated.

Comment: @labu77 Yes, as I explained, the problem is that you can have sequences of chars to create an emoji so the regular expression will match "simple" emojis and not sequences. This is why I would personnally forget about using a regex pattern (except if you just want to match simple emojis in the range of what your bbcode can handle). Using a PHP lib which is maintained seems to be a better long term solution. Depending on the CMS behind, you might find a plugin doing that too.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match should be the function to help you. That way you get an array with all of the Emojis found. Then you can use str_replace to replace all the emojis.

In example:

```
$foundemoji = preg_match($regex, $data['message'], $found);
for($i = 0; $i < count($found); $i++){
    str_replace($found[$i], "[emoji]".$found[$i]."[\emoji]", $data[$message]);
}
```

Edit: $foundemoji is either 0 or 1. 1 if preg_match found something that matches the regex, 0 if not.
The found emoji is in $found.

Comment: Hi Dokik, thank you very much for helping me. I have test it and I have an error message: Count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable. Thank you for help

Comment: Just be aware that `preg_match()` will only match one occurence in your string. If you don't want to use `preg_replace()` or `preg_replace_callback()` then at least you have to use `preg_match_all()` but it would be less efficient as you are running a `str_replace()` which is not needed as it can be done with the the regex replacement itself.

Comment: @labu77 Hello, that might be because no emoji is found. Although when I test it, it also works if there are no matches.

Comment: @Dokik Starting from PHP 8.0.0 count() will throw an error if parameter isn't Countable or array.

Comment: @Hendrik That makes sense then, I only work with 7.4 so I did not know about this, thanks for informing me!